# How to refresh Linkedin oauth token if the user authorized the app through oauth2 authorization?

Tags: linkedin-api, token, access-token, linkedin-jsapi

I need to refresh the user linkedin access token without them having to go through the initial authorization process all over again. I have also looked at this documentation http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens, but It doesn't work because my users authorize the app through regular OAuth and the article uses the JS OAuth. (Not sure, if there is a difference between two processes, and if there is a difference between access tokens received from each process). Even though, I'm already logged in another tab on the same browser, 
it always prompts me to login to LinkedIn.

If I try IN.User.isAuthorized() it returns false though I'm logged in into LinkedIn and I can't seem to be able to refresh the token.

If I pass the user LinkedIn access token from my server to the JS and the user LinkedIn id IN.User.isAuthorized() always returns true even when I'm not logged in

So what I'm trying to ask is, is there a way to refresh the user linkedin oauth token thorguh JS when the user is logged in to linkedin on the same broswer like we are able do for facebook ? and what is it ?

Comment: I also looked at http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token, but the function https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken doesn't seem to exist on linkedin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refresh the token without the member being at your application.

If you want to refresh the token, the member needs to be there and you need to direct them through the authorization page. If they're signed in to LinkedIn, this will be a seamless refresh and we'll redirect page to your application.

Comment: This does not seem to be working with the JSAPI. I'm still getting 401's even though I run the IN.User.isAuthorized() command and it returns true, when I try to make a call I get a 401.