# How to refresh a linkedIn OAuth2 token serverside (or in background proces on device)

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, server-side

This has been asked before, but since two years have past since [the best awnswer so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643403/how-to-refresh-linkedin-oauth-token-if-the-user-authorized-the-app-through-oauth), and all links to the linkedin documentation are now dead because of their recent redesign, I'm giving it another shot:

**How to refresh a linkedIn OAuth2 token without the user being present in the client?**
(eg. serverside, or background-thread of an app)

It seems the only option is to trigger the authentication dialog when the user opens your app, it will be skipped, but for Mobile applications this is annoying :(

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining a refresh_token *the first time* requires the member participation. (e.g. Member logs in, obtains an `access_token` and a `refresh_token` if they consent to it). You can then  use the `refresh_token` (that you would store securely somewhere) to renew `access_tokens` without user intervention.

However, it looks like LinkedIN doesn't support `refresh_token`. So, you will have to log the user again. Now, their `access_tokens` expire in 60 days (?!). If you log the user again and the token is *not* expired (and the user has still a session with LinkedIN), then there will be no prompts. (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2)

Comment: The linkedin OAuth service does not return a refresh_token. Only the access token. Do I have to request it?

Comment: I appreciate the help Eugnio, but I read documentation and experimented with their service. What exactly is "logging the user". The way I understand, means opening a webpage with the authentication url and let it reads the cookies/session/whatever and let it redirect, this is impossible to do without the user having your app open. The user has its sessions in the browser. Not in my java thread :(